# SSRS/Power BI report builder page break on column groupings

Tags: reporting-services, pagination, powerbi, ssrs-tablix

I am creating a report with some year/month column groups (as below).

[image]

I would like to have a page break for every year group (not month group) in Power BI report builder.

I am able to do so with the row groups, but can't seem to do it with the column groups.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To have a Page Break by Column kind of defeats the purpose of the column grouping.

The second year would show below the first year which is what it would do if you were to add a Row Group by Year to your table.

To add a year grouping and page break to the current table, Add a parent Row group, set it to group by the Year and add a Page Break to break Between groups.

Since there will only be one year shown at a time, you could remove the Column grouping by Year.